# Struts2 jqGrid DatePicker in Column Filter

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, jqgrid, datepicker

I have a jsp running Struts2 jqGrid plugin. I have enabled the filter row at the top of the grid, one of the columns is a date column and I want to be able to change the textbox at the top of the column into a DatePicker.

The id of the field I'm trying to change to a DatePicker is gs_fraudBegDt

I tried the following code at the end of my page but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#gs_fraudBegDt").datePicker();
```

How do I get gs_fraudBegDt to change to a DatePicker?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

Step 1:
Add datepicker javascript to head tag... after the sj:head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2: 
Create a function that will be called from the sjg:gridColumn tag.

```
searchDatePick=function(element) {
    $(element).datepicker();
};
```

Step 3:
Add the searchoption property to your sjg:gridColumn tag. Reference the variable name from step #2 in the dataInit section.

```
searchoptions="{size: 12, maxlength: 10, dataInit:searchDatePick,attr:{title:'Select the date'} }"
```